# mysql query performance : field position

Tags: mysql, performance

Is there any rule of query stating that which is better to filter first to have the best performance? Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date <= '2012-08-01' AND random_field = 4684 AND primary_field = 355
```

vs

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE random_field = 4684 AND primary_field = 355 AND date <= '2012-08-01'
```

Which is faster? Would the position of the where field clause placing in the query affect the performance?
Should we compare the

- primary field first?
- indexed field first?
- integer field first?
- date field first?
- string field first?
- subquery field first?

Is there any good popular mysql query guide that you know of?

Comment: The order is completely irrelevant. You can use EXPLAIN to see what mysql will use for fetching records from the index.

Comment: Put it on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [DBA SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order that the conditions are placed in the `WHERE` clause does not matter at all. What matters is the indexes you have on the table.

For this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE random_field = 4684 
  AND primary_field = 355 
  AND date <= '2012-08-01' ;
```

good indexes are either `(random_field, primary_field, date)` or: `(primary_field, random_field, date)`.

Why? Because the columns (`random_field`, `primary_field`) that have an equality conditions are placed first in the index and then the column (`date`) with the range condition.

---

The name `primary_field` is rather strange. If this is indeed the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table (or if it has a `UNIQUE` constraint - and thus a unique index), this is all you need to have for this query. This (primary or unique) index is as selective as the above indexes I advised. The condition will be matched by at most one row, because of the `primary_field = @constant`, so there is no need for the extra indexes.

Comment: Also if you have PRIMARY_KEY = CONST in your WHERE condition it doesn't matter what other indexes you have.

Comment: You are right, primary comparison is enough, but it's just for the sake of an example, replace it with indexed_field, what would the outcome be?

Comment: If it's not the primary key, read the first part of my answer.

Comment: Thx. I'll vote it useful for the moment. Let the users answers and vote, we'll see

Comment: See a similar question, about Postgres, at DBA.SE: [Does the order of fields in SELECT query matter when using composite indexing?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33979/does-the-order-of-fields-in-select-query-matter-when-using-composite-indexing/33984#33984)

Comment: And another, for MySQL: [In MySQL, does the order of the columns in a WHERE clause affect query performance?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/in-mysql-does-the-order-of-the-columns-in-a-where-clause-affect-query-performan)

Answer (score 0):

we should follow some rules

```
1. comparison of primary fields should come first and then indexed (because this will filter out required value )
2. Date or range wise (example 2<id<6) should come at the end.
```

Comment: The answer seems logical. But I need some kind of well documented guide, since each person tell a different answer.. Let the user vote